# Python stringTypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Tags: python

def SRM(stringToReverse):
   if len(stringToReverse) == 0 or stringToReverse==None :
       return
   return  stringToReverse[len(stringToReverse) - 1] + SRM(stringToReverse[:len(stringToReverse) - 1]
   #print(temp, end='')`enter code here`
SRM("MY NAME IS KHAN")

Comment: you can't take the `len(None)`

Comment: Don't name your variables `str`; it shadows the builtin type.

Comment: The None is in the way there, why do you have `None` as default parameter?  https://repl.it/repls/ColorfulPassionateObservatory?

Comment: rev(str=None) ?? is this unintentional ?. Also if you are unaware str is a python built in command for specifying strings. It is advised that you do not use 'str' as a variable name.

Comment: The `=None` is unnecessary here. That implies that the argument is optional, which makes no sense for a reverse function.

Comment: You are specifying string default value to be None.

Comment: I dont know whether this would be helpful but you can reverse a string like `your_string[::-1]`

Comment: #mad_,thanks mad_, I really appreciate you for your valuable suggestion,but   I don't want to use inbuilt function.

Comment: @Sanjeevkumar your edit made it impossible to read, please revert back to the original question. And please mark the most helpful answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is a homework question, and I understand that you are looking for "How to reverse a string using recursion".

First of all, as many people mentioned, please take out all "str"s and replace them with "myStr" or something. You don't want to mask anything built-in.

Secondly, there is a problem with your recursion logic.

Issue1: The base case. What do you want your function to return when it traverses through your string, and ends at an empty string? Why does that return not return anything? Please correct line 3 to `return ""`.

Issue2: Your function returns `NoneType`. That is because the recursive case is problematic. Your `print` is trying to concatenate the string of `str[len(str) - 1]` with the result of `rev(str[:len(str) - 1])`, but this latter piece is not a `return`ed string, it is nothing! Why do you print, but not return? Replace your `print` with `return` so that recursive call actually produces a string for you that you can later combine with the first sliced string.

So the code should look like the following, but again, please fully understand the recursive logic. Otherwise you'll get stuck at the next recursion question.

```
def rev(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return ""
    return x[len(x) - 1] + rev(x[:len(x) - 1])

print(rev("ABC DEF"))
# Correctly prints: FED CBA.
```

Comment: thanks FatihAkici, I got the issue. def SRM(stringToReverse):
   if len(stringToReverse) == 0 or stringToReverse==None :
       return 
   return  stringToReverse[len(stringToReverse) - 1] + SRM(stringToReverse[:len(stringToReverse) - 1])
print(SRM("MY NAME IS KHAN"))

Comment: Are you sure it works @Sanjeevkumar? I am getting error when I run your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't pass a string to your function your str variable is None.
Calling your function like that

```
rev()
```

will probably produce your error.
Change line 2 to:

```
if str is None or len(str) == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
if len(str) == 0:
```

to

```
if not rev_string:
```

This would take care of None and an empty string.

edit: as jwodder commented; use another name for str (rev_string or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the power of exteded slices:

```
def reverser(s=None):
    if not s:
        return ''
    return s[::-1]
```